# How to pass Section and Row specified tableview cell content through a segue?

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, segue

I've often used prepareForSegue to pass stuff forward to the next view controller. No problem when my tableview doesn't use sections.  But I've added sections to my latest project.  Now I don't know how to use prepareForSegue because it doesn't receive the indexpath, which contains the section reference.  What am I missing?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: post your code for didSelectRowAtIndexpath

Comment: Actually, that's empty.  I don't use that when I don't have sections.  What should go in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your prepareForSegue method, just use:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

and pass that along to the destinationViewController.